# Alternative to editing httpd-vhosts.conf for ServerAliases on shared hosting?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, virtualhost, serveralias

greetings. i need to set up some ServerAlias records so multiple domains can be mapped to the same application folder however with this shared server i don't have access to the httpd-vhosts.conf file. Can this be done some other way, using .htaccess perhaps?

Comment: sorry, i should add that my dev set up is xampp on windows (hence the vhosts file) whereas the production server will be apache. i don't know if there's a different file that can be edited for apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ServerAlias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#serveralias) directive can be defined in *virtual host* context but not in *htaccess*.

[VirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#virtualhost) directive can only be defined in *server config* context. The `httpd-vhosts.conf` is linked/included into main config file and therefore part of the *server config* context.

P.S. xampp uses Apache as web server, so you will have Apache in both places anyway.

If you want to modify any parameters of `<VirtualHost>` you may write an email to the hosting company to see if they can do it for you. But I think that it most likely will be declined as virtually all operations on configuring `<VirtualHost>` are fully automated no manual editing is involved, and even if done the changes may get lost when you/they modify server config via control panel.